# Passing pointer argument to unsafe.Pointer: found bad pointer in Go heap

Tags: go, unsafe, unsafe-pointers

What are the problems with using

**Approach 1:**

```golang
func Encode(v *float32) []byte {
    return unsafe.Slice((*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(v)), 4)
}
```

over

**Approach 2**

```golang
func Encode(v float32) []byte {
    return unsafe.Slice((*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&v)), 4)
}
```

Both are run on Little Endian System. The only difference is that **Approach 1** accepts a pointer as an argument, while **Approach 2** accepts a value as an argument.

I was debugging an issue related to

`fatal error: found bad pointer in Go heap (incorrect use of unsafe or cgo?)`

`found pointer to free object | bad use of unsafe.Pointer?`

and I finally found the root cause could be due to **Approach 1** usage. Could someone please let me know what could be the issue with **Approach 1**? Is it generally recommended to use **Approach 2**?

Please note that `float32` is one of the functions. There are other encode functions that accept `byte arrays`, `int8` etc as well.

```golang
type Uuid [16]byte

func EncodeUuid(v *Uuid) []byte {
    return unsafe.Slice((*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(v)), UuidSize)
}
```

[This SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74834599/1609570) mentioned that the original variable could be GC'ed before the `Encode()` function is called. Attempting to access the memory pointed to by an already freed pointer can result in a "found pointer to free object" error.

Below are the error logs found during execution.

**Error Log 1**

```
runtime: marked free object in span 0x7fef20c4c8a8, elemsize=24 freeindex=0 (bad use of unsafe.Pointer? try -d=checkptr)
0xc14a028000 free  unmarked
0xc14a028018 free  unmarked
0xc14a028030 free  unmarked
0xc14a028048 free  unmarked
0xc14a028060 free  unmarked
0xc14a028078 free  marked   zombie
0x000000c14a028078:  0x000000c0003f2800  0x0000000000000800 
0x000000c14a028088:  0x0000000000000800 
0xc14a028090 free  unmarked
0xc14a029fc8 free  unmarked
0xc14a029fe0 free  unmarked
fatal error: found pointer to free object

goroutine 1482447 [running]:
runtime.throw({0x29b9a01?, 0xc14a028090?})
    /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/panic.go:1047 +0x5d fp=0xc2555a2ae0 sp=0xc2555a2ab0 pc=0x44775d
runtime.(*mspan).reportZombies(0x7fef20c4c8a8)
    /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/mgcsweep.go:788 +0x2e5 fp=0xc2555a2b60 sp=0xc2555a2ae0 pc=0x435dc5
```

**Error Log 2**

```
runtime: pointer 0xc079e0001d to unallocated span span.base()=0xc079dfe000 span.limit=0xc079e2e010 span.state=0
runtime: found in object at *(0xc032b5c180+0x28)
object=0xc032b5c180 s.base()=0xc032b5c000 s.limit=0xc032b5e000 s.spanclass=20 s.elemsize=128 s.state=mSpanInUse
 *(object+0) = 0x0
 *(object+8) = 0x400000016
 *(object+16) = 0xffffffff00000020
 *(object+24) = 0x3a665e0
 *(object+32) = 0xc0dde3d110
 *(object+40) = 0xc079e0001d <==
 *(object+48) = 0x8000
 *(object+56) = 0x8008
 *(object+64) = 0x0
 *(object+72) = 0x0
 *(object+80) = 0x0
 *(object+88) = 0x2
 *(object+96) = 0x2000
 *(object+104) = 0x6174620
 *(object+112) = 0x101
 *(object+120) = 0x0
fatal error: found bad pointer in Go heap (incorrect use of unsafe or cgo?)
```

**Error Log 3**

```
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x2 addr=0x450608 pc=0x468c46]

goroutine 1202 [running]:
runtime.throw({0x3f96b81?, 0x0?})
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:1047 +0x5d fp=0xc006433cd0 sp=0xc006433ca0 pc=0x454c7d
runtime.sigpanic()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:819 +0x369 fp=0xc006433d20 sp=0xc006433cd0 pc=0x46ce09
runtime.(*waitq).enqueue(...)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/chan.go:766
runtime.selectgo(0xc006433fb0, 0xc006433ed8, 0x2710?, 0x0, 0x0?, 0x1)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/select.go:317 +0x7c6 fp=0xc006433e80 sp=0xc006433d20 pc=0x468c46
```

Any suggestion would be really helpful!

**PS:** The issue occurs rarely when the GC kicks in. So in order to have aggressive GC to test the scenario, I am currently using

```bash
GODEBUG=invalidptr=1,cgocheck=1,madvdontneed=1 GOGC=2 GOMEMLIMIT=10MiB ./my-executable
```

Comment: I don’t think Encode is directly causing the problem, rather it could be how you are using the result. Can you create a [mre]?

Comment: note that the other answer you linked talks about early garbage collection because the parameter there is a `uintptr`. Your `Encode` function takes a regular `*float32`

Comment: I don't think converting a `*float` to a `*byte` is legal, the unsafe package allows conversion of `*T1` to `*T2` only if "T2 is no larger than T1 and that the two share an equivalent memory layout".

Comment: Also the second approach is no better than `res := make([]byte, 4); binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(res, math.Float32bits(v))`

Comment: Write EncodeUuid as `func EncodeUuid(v *Uuid) []byte { return v[:] }`.  I don't know if this will fix the issue, but here's a version of Encode that reduces use of the `unsafe` package: `func Encode(v *float32) []byte { return (*[4]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(v))[:] }`.

Comment: @CeriseLimón, `UnsafeSlice` was written so you don’t have to use that type of array conversion any more. It is equivalent but does not require a constant-typed size.